# Would a polarizer filter work on the ipad camera to stop screen glare reflections on eyeglasses?

Tags: polarizer

Would a polarizer filter work on the ipad camera to stop screen glare on eyeglasses? Or would screen glare reflections still be present on the eyeglasses?

Comment: On glasses of someone you are photographing with an Ipad? More info and details are needed in order to get an informed answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some effective techniques for photographing subjects who wear glasses?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6885/what-are-some-effective-techniques-for-photographing-subjects-who-wear-glasses)

Comment: Do you _have_ a polarizer? Why not try it? You don't need to run out and buy one if you have a pair of polarized sunglasses handy. OTOH, if you _do_ have a "circular" polarizer made for photography use, then be sure to hold it with the right way facing out.

Comment: _stop screen glare reflections on eyeglasses_... Do you mean glare from the iPad screen reflecting off your glasses when using the front camera? Like, for Zoom or Facetime calls?

Comment: @scottbb yes, this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a small polarizer filter over the camera, but it is probably easier to try changing the angle of, or in relation to, the light source. The glare is ultimately created by the light source.

Answer (score 1):

Screens/monitors are polarized in order to improve their viewing angles. So the light they emit is polarized and a polarizing filter will block it.

However, you may find it is not completely effective due to different angles involved (i.e. uneven effect on heavily curved lenses)